# Diagram Linus Pauling tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am try draw Diagram Linus Pauling in tikz, have possibility draw arrow example picture [image: Model Diagram]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{dot/.style={fill=orange!20,circle}}
    \tikzset{set/.style={<-,red}}
    \foreach\l[count=\c] in {Q,P,...,K}
    {
        \draw[dotted] (0,\c) -- (5.0, \c);
        \node at (-1.0, \c){\bfseries\l};
    }
    
    \foreach\n[count=\y] in {7,...,1}
    {
        \draw[dotted] (0,\y) -- (5.0,\y);
        \node at (-0.5,\y){\bfseries\n};
    }
    
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,4}
    {
        \draw[dotted] (\x,0) -- (\x,8);
        \node at (\x,-0.5){\x};
    }
%%% Arrow 
   \draw[set] (0.5,6.5)--(1.5,7.5);
    \draw[set] (0.5,5.5)--(1.5,6.5);
    \draw[set] (0.5,4.5)--(2.5,6.5);
    %%%%% S %%%
    \node[dot] (1) at (1,7){1s};
    \node[dot] (2) at (1,6){2s};
    \node[dot] at (1,5){3s};
    \node[dot] at (1,4){4s};
    \node[dot] at (1,3){5s};
    \node[dot] at (1,2){6s};
    \node[dot] at (1,1){7s};
    %%%%% Block p
    \node[dot] at (2,6){2p};
    \node[dot] at (2,5){3p};
    \node[dot] at (2,4){4p};
    \node[dot] at (2,3){5p};
    \node[dot] at (2,2){6p};
    %\node[dot] at (2,1){};
    %%%%% Block d
    \node[dot] at (3,5){3d};
    \node[dot] at (3,4){4d};
    \node[dot] at (3,3){4d};
    \node[dot] at (3,2){6p};
    %%%%% Block f
    \node[dot] at (4,4){4f};
    \node[dot] at (4,3){5f};    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Maybe something like this:

[image: linus pauling diagram]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
      
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
    \tikzset{%
            dot/.style={fill=orange!20,circle},
            gdot/.style={fill=violet!20,circle},
            set/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[red]{Stealth}}
      }}}}
    \foreach\l[count=\c] in {Q,P,...,K}
    {
        \draw[dotted] (0,\c) -- (5.0, \c);
        \node at (-1.0, \c){\bfseries\l};
    }
    
    \foreach\n[count=\y] in {7,...,1}
    {
        \draw[dotted] (0,\y) -- (5.0,\y);
        \node at (-0.5,\y){\bfseries\n};
    }
    
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,4}
    {
        \draw[dotted] (\x,0) -- (\x,8);
        \node at (\x,-0.5){\x};
    }

    %%%%% S %%%
    \node[dot] (1) at (1,7){1s};
    \node[dot] (2s) at (1,6){2s};
    \node[dot] (3s) at (1,5){3s};
    \node[dot] (4s)at (1,4){4s};
    \node[dot] (5s) at (1,3){5s};
    \node[dot] (6s) at (1,2){6s};
    \node[dot] (7s) at (1,1){7s};
    %%%%% Block p
    \node[gdot] (2p) at (2,6){2p};
    \node[gdot] (3p) at (2,5){3p};
    \node[gdot] (4p) at (2,4){4p};
    \node[gdot] (5p) at (2,3){5p};
    \node[gdot] (6p) at (2,2){6p};
    \node[gdot] (7p) at (2,1){7p};
    %\node[dot] at (2,1){};
    %%%%% Block d
    \node[dot] (3d) at (3,5){3d};
    \node[dot] (4d) at (3,4){4d};
    \node[dot] (5d) at (3,3){5d};
    \node[dot] (6d) at (3,2){6d};
    %%%%% Block f
    \node[gdot] (4f) at (4,4){4f};
    \node[gdot] (5f) at (4,3){5f};   
    
    \draw (1) edge [set,out=-135,in=45,looseness=6] (2s); 
    \draw (2s) edge [set,out=-135,in=45,looseness=5] (2p);
    \draw [red] (2p) -- (3s);
    \draw (3s) edge [set,out=-135,in=45,looseness=5] (3p); 
    \draw[red] (3p)--(4s);
    \draw (4s) edge [set,out=-135,in=45,looseness=3] (3d); 
    \draw[red] (3d)--(4p) (4p) -- (5s);
    \draw (5s) edge [set,out=-135,in=45,looseness=3] (4d);
    \draw[red] (4d)--(5p) (5p) -- (6s);
    \draw (6s) edge [set,out=-135,in=45,looseness=2.5] (4f);
    \draw[red] (4f) -- (5d) (5d) -- (6p) (6p) -- (7s);
    \draw (7s) edge [set,out=-135,in=45,looseness=2.5] (5f);
    \draw[red] (5f) -- (6d) (6d) -- (7p) (7p) edge[red,-Stealth]++ (-.5,-.5);
    
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I did not change anything relevant in your code, but you could have taken advantage of placing your node with relative adressing (i.e. one depending on another) instead of giving those absolute coordinates. I just had to double the scale in order to let some more space between the nodes.

### EDIT: ANOTHER (BETTER?) DIAGRAM

I decided to do something else. I wanted to find something a bit more automatic but ended up with a *manual* graph along the nodes. But anyway, you could find it more attractive.

[image: Linus Pauling V2]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{%
    adot/.style={fill=orange!20,circle,minimum width=.8cm},
    bdot/.style={fill=violet!20,circle,minimum width=.8cm},
        % Arrow color
    arrcol/.style={violet},
        % No arrow
    narr/.style={violet,line width=1.5pt},
        % Arrow in the middle
    marr/.style={narr,postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[arrcol]{Stealth[scale=1]}}
      }}},
      % Arrow at the begining
    barr/.style={narr,postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.05 with {\arrow[arrcol]{Stealth[scale=1]}}
      }}}
    }
            
\begin{document}
      
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\d{2} % Node distance
        \path (0,0)
            node[adot] (1-s) {1s} 
            \foreach \i in {2,...,7}
                {--++ (0,-\d) node[adot] (\i-s) {\i s} coordinate[midway](\i-1)};
        \path (\d,-\d)
            node[bdot] (2-p) {2p} 
            \foreach \i in {3,...,7}
                {--++ (0,-\d) node[bdot] (\i-p) {\i p} coordinate[midway](\i-2)};
        \path (2*\d,-2*\d)
            node[adot] (3-d) {3d} 
            \foreach \i in {4,...,6}
                {--++ (0,-\d) node[adot] (\i-d) {\i d} coordinate[midway](\i-3)};
        \path (3*\d,-3*\d)
            node[bdot] (4-f) {4f} --++ (0,-\d) node[bdot] (5-f) {5f} coordinate[midway](5-4);
        
        
        \path (7-s) --++ (0,-.5*\d) coordinate (8-1);
        \path (7-p) --++ (0,-.5*\d) coordinate (8-2);
        \path (6-d) --++ (0,-.5*\d) coordinate (7-3);
        \path (5-f) --++ (0,-.5*\d) coordinate (6-4);
        
        \path (2-p) --++ (0,.5*\d) coordinate (2-2);
        \path (3-d) --++ (0,.5*\d) coordinate (3-3);
        \path (4-f) --++ (0,.5*\d) coordinate (4-4);
 
% Uncomment to see intermediate coordinate      
%       \foreach \i in {2,...,8} \node at (\i-1) {\i-1};
%       \foreach \i in {2,...,8} \node at (\i-2) {\i-2};
%       \foreach \i in {3,...,7} \node at (\i-3) {\i-3};
%       \foreach \i in {4,...,6} \node at (\i-4) {\i-4};
        

            \draw[narr] (1-s) --++ (1,1);
            \path   (1-s) edge [narr,out=-135,in=-135,looseness=3] (2-1)
                    (2-1) edge [barr,out=45,in=45,looseness=3] (2-s)
                    
                    (2-s) edge [narr,out=-135,in=-135,looseness=3] (3-1)
                    (3-1) edge [barr] (2-2) 
                    (2-2) edge [barr,out=45,in=45,looseness=3] (2-p)
                    (2-p) edge [narr] (3-s)
                    
                    (3-s) edge [narr,out=-135,in=-135,looseness=3] (4-1)
                    (4-1) edge [barr] (3-2) 
                    (3-2) edge [barr,out=45,in=45,looseness=3] (3-p)
                    (3-p) edge [narr] (4-s)
                    
                    (4-s) edge [narr,out=-135,in=-135,looseness=3] (5-1)
                    (5-1) edge [barr] (3-3)
                    (3-3) edge [barr,out=45,in=45,looseness=3] (3-d)
                    (3-d) edge [narr] (4-p)
                    (4-p) edge [narr] (5-s)
                    
                    (5-s) edge [narr,out=-135,in=-135,looseness=3] (6-1)
                    (6-1) edge [barr] (4-3)
                    (4-3) edge [barr,out=45,in=45,looseness=3] (4-d)
                    (4-d) edge [narr] (5-p)
                    (5-p) edge [narr] (6-s)
                    
                    (6-s) edge [narr,out=-135,in=-135,looseness=3] (7-1)
                    (7-1) edge [barr] (4-4)
                    (4-4) edge [barr,out=45,in=45,looseness=3] (4-f)
                    (4-f) edge [narr] (5-d)
                    (5-d) edge [narr] (6-p)
                    (6-p) edge [narr] (7-s)
                    
                    (7-s) edge [narr,out=-135,in=-135,looseness=3] (8-1)
                    (8-1) edge [barr] (5-4)
                    (5-4) edge [barr,out=45,in=45,looseness=3] (5-f)
                    (5-f) edge [narr] (6-d)
                    (6-d) edge [narr] (7-p)
                    ;
                \draw[narr,-{Stealth[scale=1]}] (7-p) --++ (-1,-1); 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like very much the last image. +1.

Comment: Thanks very help I am like +1

Answer (score 7):

I offer a slightly more compact solution, drawing all inside `\foreach` commands.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset
{% styles for the nodes
  s/.style={fill=red!20},
  p/.style={fill=green!20},
  d/.style={fill=blue!20},
  f/.style={fill=yellow!20}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, y={(0cm,-1cm)},line cap=rect]
  \foreach\y in {1,...,8}
  {%
    \ifnum\y > 1
      \draw[thick]    (0.5*\y+1.25,0.5*\y-0.75) arc (-135:45:{0.125*sqrt(2)});
    \fi
    \draw[thick,->]   (0.5*\y+1.5,0.5*\y-0.5) -- (0.5,\y+0.5);
    \ifnum \y < 8
      \draw[thick,->] (0.5,\y+0.5) arc (225:45:{0.125*sqrt(2)}) --
                      (0.5*\y+1.75,0.5*\y-0.25);
    \fi
  }
  \foreach\y in {1,...,7}
  {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxx{6-abs(4.5-\y)}
    \foreach[count=\x]\i in {s,p,d,f}
    {%
      \ifnum \x < \maxx
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ne{4*\x-2)} % number of electrons
        \draw[\i] (\x,\y) circle (0.25);
        \node  at (\x,\y) {$\y\mathrm{\i}^{\ne}$};
      \fi
   }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I was trying to do something like this in the first place. Glad you provided it (and it's easily customizable).

Comment: More simple custom, Thanks for help